# tracking a different branch on github

Tags: git, github

I am trying to track a different branch of a github project.
The project is restful_authentication:

http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication

However, what I really want to clone is the modular branch:

http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/modular

I found this guide:

http://github.com/guides/showing-and-tracking-remote-branches

and tried a few commands like:

```
git checkout --track -b lmod http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/modular
```

and

```
git checkout --track -b lmod git://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git/modular
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
fatal: git checkout: updating paths is incompatible with switching branches
```

Any thoughts on the correct way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot just clone a branch, you have to clone the full repository:

```
git clone git://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication.git
```

Then you can use a tracking branch in your local repository:

```
cd restful-authentication
git checkout --track -b lmod origin/modular
```

Note that, after cloning, git has set up a "remote" with the name "origin" for the remote repository and "origin/modular" identifies the "modular" branch of the "origin" remote.